# Find rows in Postgres where string is in any random order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently working on a Postgres SQL query that will check for rows that match a space separated string (3 words) in any random order.

For example I want to look for a row that matches "lorem ipsum dolor" it should return row id 0.

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | sentence          |
| 0  | lorem dolor ipsum |
| 1  | lorem ipsum       |
| 2  | ipsum dolor       |
| 3  | ipsum dolor       |
+----+-------------------+
```

So it has to meet the following conditions:

- the same 3 words in this case
- In any random order:

  1. Lorem ipsum dolor
  2. dolor Lorem ipsum
  3. ipsum dolor Lorem
  4. Lorem dolor ipsum
  5. ...

If I'm correct this should result in 3 * 3 * 3 = 27 possible formats. But this can imagine that this quite intensive when using more words. How can I achieve this without hammering the server, or what is the right direction to look for.

Comment: similar to and a alternation operator http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: What if there are more than 3 words in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method, which Clodoaldo Neto described, is good for sorting the words. If performance is crucial for you, you can even create an index for that to improve lookup speed. Create a custom function `sortwords` first:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sortwords (words text) RETURNS text AS 
   $$ SELECT string_agg(lower(s), ' ' order by s) 
      FROM regexp_split_to_table($1, '\s+') s(s) $$ 
      LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

The keyword `IMMUTABLE` designates, that the function result is solely dependant on it's argument, and hence the function is suitable for creating an index.

Then, create the index:

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_sortwords ON mytable (sortwords(sentence));
```

and perform selects like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sortwords(sentence) = sortwords('some words');
```

This has the advantage, that the sorting of the words (which can be quite costy) is only performed once per row (either when the index is created or on row insertion).

Comment: Switched to this solution. Performance is really good an much cleaner. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

```
with t(s) as (values
    ('lorem dolor ipsum'),
    ('lorem ipsum'),
    ('ipsum dolor'),
    ('ipsum dolor')
)
select *
from t
where 
    (
        select string_agg(lower(s), ' ' order by s)
        from regexp_split_to_table(s, '\s+') s(s)
    )
    =
    (
        select string_agg(lower(s), ' ' order by s)
        from regexp_split_to_table('lorem ipsum dolor', '\s+') s(s)
    )
;
         s         
-------------------
 lorem dolor ipsum
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER

Comment: Thanks this works like charm. Only issue right now is the performance, but for now it works.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is to break your search text and add then as filters like this:

```
select * from test 
 where sentence like '%lorem%'
   and sentence like '%ipsum%'
   and sentence like '%dolor%';
```

This will get all sentences with this three words in it, in any order.
See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/28ac1/3

**EDIT**

In order to get the results in any case you have to add a `lower` function to the field `sentence` like this:

```
select * from test 
 where lower(sentence) like '%lorem%'
   and lower(sentence) like '%ipsum%'
   and lower(sentence) like '%dolor%';
```

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6dfb9/1

**EDIT 2**

As OP stated in comments that He need only the registries that contains only three searched words I would go for this approach:

```
select * from test 
 where position('lorem' in lower(sentence))>0
   and position('ipsum' in lower(sentence))>0
   and position('dolor' in lower(sentence))>0
   and array_length(regexp_split_to_array(sentence, E'\\s+')::text[],1) =
       array_length(regexp_split_to_array('lorem ipsum dolor', E'\\s+')::text[],1)
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a5404/5

Comment: But correct me if i'm wrong. This wil also return e.g. `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`. The result should be contain only the 3 words in any random order. My question  wasn't clear enough, will update it.

Comment: @lvdp  Yes you are right and yes that wasn't clear! I will update.

Comment: The main shortcoming is that it must be dynamically built.  The last version matches [`'loremyy dolorxx ipsumzz'`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a4ee5/1).